# Finding averages from reading a file using Bash Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, file-io

I am trying to write a bash script that reads a file 'names.txt' and will compute the average of peoples grades. For instance, names.txt looks something like this.

```
900706845 Harry Thompson 70 80 90
900897665 Roy Ludson 90 90 90
```

The script should read the line, print out the ID# of the person, the average of the three test scores and the corresponding letter grade. So the output needs to look like this

```
900706845 80 B
900897665 90 A
```

Heres what I have

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cat names.txt | while read x
    do 
         $SUM=0; for i in 'names.txt'; do SUM=$(($SUM + $i));
         done;

         echo $SUM/3
    done
```

I understand the echo will only print out the averages at this point, but I am trying to atleast get it to compute the averages before I attempt the other parts as well. Baby steps!

Comment: for one thing, the `for` loop doesn't do what you think it does. Try: `for i in 'names.txt'; do echo $i ; done` to see what it actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a name1 name2 g1 g2 g3
do
   avg=$(echo "($g1+$g2+$g3)/3" | bc)
   echo $a $name1 $name2 $avg
done < names.txt
```

Output:

```
900706845 Harry Thompson 80
900897665 Roy Ludson 90
```

Comment: @jaypal `bc` is not bash.

Comment: Agree, a point could be added that bash doesn't do floating point numbering incase OP runs into such numbers.

Comment: This actually really helped me, didnt know by saying read a name1 name2 g1 g2 g3, it would create variables for the different parts of the text. But the finding the average is not working. How would i create a avg variable to add up the 3 grades and divide by 3. I cant figure out how to referance them the correct way

Comment: @Tree55Topz This line `avg=$(echo "($g1+$g2+$g3)/3" | bc)` does that for you. If your grades or the avg from grades aren't going to be in floating point, you can do `avg=$((($g1 + $g2 + $g3)/3))`

Comment: @jaypal it does not work. I try to print it out using echo $id $avg and it says bc: command not found and avg: command not found

Comment: @Tree55Topz If you don't mind can you please update the question with your current script and error message when you run it?

Comment: @Tree55Topz: the `avg: command not found` error sounds like you added spaces around the assignment; you can't do that in shell.  As for `bc: command not found`, that sounds like either you've screwed up your PATH or you don't have `bc` on your machine so it is effectively defective.  Go find and install it.

Answer (score 0):

The ID#s and averages can be obtained as follows:

```
$ awk '{sum=0; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i ; print $1, sum/3}' names.txt 
900706845 80
900897665 90
```

Guessing at how to compute grades, one can do:

```
$ awk '{sum=0; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i ; ave=sum/3; print $1, ave, substr("FFFFFDCBA", ave/10, 1) }' names.txt 
900706845 80 B
900897665 90 A
```

The above solutions work for any number of tests but names are limited to 2 words.  If there will always be three tests but names can be any number of words, then use:

```
$ awk '{ave=($(NF-2)+$(NF-1)+$NF)/3; print $1, ave, substr("FFFFFDCBA", ave/10, 1) }' names.txt
900706845 80 B
900897665 90 A
```

Comment: You can do `awk '{print $1, ($NF+$(NF-1)+$(NF-2))/3}' name.txt` but thats not the point. OP is attempting at `bash`. Not that I would not do it with `awk`. :)

Comment: I was aiming for code that continues to work even if the instructor gives the students another test.

Comment: Would you please also aim for people with 3-word names? ;)

Comment: Aaah!! Good point! `;)`. He doesn't enroll students with more than 3 word names.

Comment: Do i just need that one line of code? I tried it and it didn't seem to work. Both by itself and with the do while. I got a no such file or directory error.

Comment: @Tree55Topz  Yes, it is just one line of code. There is no `do...while` loop with this solution. I just copied my answer from here to the bash prompt and it works for me. Are you running it in the directory where names.txt is located? What, precisely, is the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Customize `gradeLetter` for your own needs:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
  function gradeLetter(g)
  {
    if (g >= 90) return "A";
    if (g >= 80) return "B";
    if (g >= 70) return "C";
    if (g >= 60) return "D";
    return "E"
  }
  {
    avgGrade = ($(NF) + $(NF - 1) + $(NF - 2)) / 3;
    print $1, avgGrade, gradeLetter(avgGrade)
  }' names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With a awk one-liner:

```
awk '{ AVG = int( ( $(NF-2) + $(NF-1) + $(NF) ) / 3 ) ; if ( AVG >= 90 ) { GRADE = "A" } else if ( AVG >= 80 ) { GRADE = "B" } else if ( AVG >= 70 ) { GRADE = "C" } else if ( AVG >= 60 ) { GRADE = "D" } else { GRADE = "F" } ; print $1, AVG, GRADE }' file
```

Let's look at the details:

```
awk '{

  # Calculate average
  AVG = int( ( $(NF-2) + $(NF-1) + $(NF) ) / 3 )

  # Calculate grade
  if ( AVG >= 90 ) { GRADE = "A" }
  else if ( AVG >= 80 ) { GRADE = "B" }
  else if ( AVG >= 70 ) { GRADE = "C" }
  else if ( AVG >= 60 ) { GRADE = "D" }
  else { GRADE = "F" }

  print $1, AVG, GRADE

}' file
```