# Adding integers from file Bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-io

I need to add up integers and find the average between them from a file. Here is what they look like in the file

```
70 80 90
```

so in my bash script I reference them like this

```
    cat num.txt | while read n1 n2 n3
    set $n1 $n2 $n3
```

and when I try to find the average

```
    avg = $(($n1+$n2+$n3))/3
    echo $avg
```

This is not working and I have tried so many other things but I guess Im just not referencing them correctly

Comment: What did you learn from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959819/finding-averages-from-reading-a-file-using-bash-scripting)?

Comment: The `while` syntax is broken; you should drop the `while`.  You then have to worry about pipelines and setting variables in the pipeline. The `set` command doesn't do what you seem to think it will do. Typically, calculating the average involves dividing by some number (3 for the average of 3 numbers).

Comment: I learned how to set the variables from the file using while read, but now the part that is not working is the referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
while read n1 n2 n3; do
  avg=$((($n1 + $n2 + $n3)/3))
  echo $avg
done < num.txt
```

This will not work for floating point numbers. `Bash` natively doesn't support floating point. For that you need to do:

```
avg=$(echo "($n1 + $n2 + $n3)/3" | bc)
```

Here is a good [reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to read from files.

Comment: Note that `bc` uses `scale=0` by default.  If the values were 70, 80 and 89, the output from `bc` would be 79; the output from `bc -l` would be 79.66666666666666666666; the output from `echo "scale=2; (70 + 80 + 89)/3" | bc` is
79.66.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. Your comments always adds value. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably do best with something like:

```
set -- $(cat num.txt)
SUM=0
for i in "$@"
do ((SUM+=${i}))
done
echo "Sum = $SUM; Average = $(($SUM / $#))"
```

This assumes (as [Fredrik Pihl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297323/fredrik-pihl) points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960686/adding-integers-from-file-bash/21960757?noredirect=1#comment33273901_21960757)) that integer arithmetic is sufficient.  If you need floating point arithmetic, use `bc` (assuming it is installed on your system; if it isn't, get it!).

```
set -- $(cat num.txt)
SUM=$(echo "$*" | sed 's/ / + /g' | bc -l)
AVG=$(echo "$SUM / $#" | bc -l)
echo "Sum = $SUM; Number = $#; Average = $AVG"
```

If you put your mind to it, you can devise mechanisms to do both sum and average in a single invocation of `bc`.  The `-l` option gives a scale of 20 (20 decimal places).  If that's excessive, use a variation such as:

```
SUM=$(echo "$*" | sed 's/ / + /g; s/^/scale=2; /' | bc)
```

If you feel that's too clumsy, it is probably time to move to a scripting language such as `awk`, Perl or Python.

Answer (score 1):

awk is a better tool for this as it already processes input file line by line. Consider this awk script:

```
awk '{for (c=1; c<=NF; c++) sum+=$c; printf "%.2f", sum/NF}' file
```

Added advantage of `awk` is its ability to support floating point arithmetic as well (as you can see in `"%.2f"` output format).

Comment: Lol :) I am actually boarding a flight to DC and reached airport little early. Now I will be quiet for next 20-22 hours at least.

Comment: Welcome back!! Safe Travels!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but here it is, for any number of numbers per line, in pure bash:

```
while read -a v; do
    s=0
    for x in ${v[@]}; do (( s += x )); done
    echo $(( s / ${#v[@]} ))
done < num.txt
```